# how to remove the parent directory if the 2nd child directory empty?

Tags: unix, directory

i have two directory which are 09Jan/WW and Jan/WWL. if the 09Jan/WW directory empty, it will remoce the parent directory but if the Jan/WWL directory empty, remove only the sub,WWL. how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rmdir command to remove a directory. It will remove the directory entry specified by each dirname operand, which must refer to an empty directory.

For example, to remove a directory called "cppcode", enter:
rmdir cppcode

Note: A directory must be empty before it can be removed. Use rm command to remove all files from a directory:
cd cppcode
rm *.cpp
cd ..
rmdir cppcode

You can also recursively remove directories and subdirectories. The directory will be emptied of files and removed using rm command:
rm -r oldletters